# ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Error parsing [service]. The [service] resource is not properly specified. Failed to find attribute [service]

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy my nodejs application to cloud run using the following command

```
 gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/[project-id]/helloworld --platform managed
```

Before running this command I built two cloud build images and trying to deploy the latest build using above command. But getting the following error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Error parsing [service].
The [service] resource is not properly specified.
Failed to find attribute [service]. The attribute can be set in the following ways:
- provide the argument [SERVICE] on the command line
- specify the service name from an interactive prompt
```

I don't know which is causing error. Can anybody help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try specifying the [Service ID](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#SERVICE) as an argument, replacing `my-service` with the desired name:

```
gcloud run deploy my-service --image gcr.io/[project-id]/helloworld --platform managed
```

Also, make sure you're using the latest Cloud SDK with [`gcloud components update`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update).

Answer (score 0):

`$ gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/cloudrun/hello --platform managed` should prompt you to pick a platform, pick a region and a service name. Please try with this command.

In your command, make sure to replace `[project-id]` with you GCP project ID.

Comment: yes, I am adding correct project id in the [project-id] section. Still, I am facing the issue

Comment: Does `gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/cloudrun/hello --platform managed` works for you?

Comment: I tried above command by replacing "hello" with my service name but still getting the same error